# Installing Leopard in target mode from Catalina

Tags: catalina, leopard

I have two working instalments of Catalina and I have a an old Power book G4 12 inch that I need to install a new OS on.
As far as I can understand the latest OS I can install is Leopard (10.5) and I had one old dmg that I used many years ago to install from and I have also downloaded from different repositories online that has old OS versions.
I've tried to install from  several different USB keys but the computer fails to recognise it as a start up option, not when booting holding down alt key and selecting it as a startup option (with it doesn't see it as)
My last try to do it with was to do it as a target mode from my one of my Catalina machines where I have a firewire card but will that at all be possible.
Am I wrong in the assumption in that Catalina can only do guid formats and will it even recognise the Leopard OS since its 32 and not a 64 OS.
Does anyone know of anyway I can do this or a smart workaround for this.
Thank you in advance.
Karl

Comment: It is unlikely that you can do target disk mode because the Leopard installer *won't run* on Catalina. How are you creating the install media? Burning the ISO/DMG to a DVD, or what?

Comment: All different ways ;-) I've done two different usb sticks and they are apple formated (not guid) and Ive tried two different dmg and one iso I found online and also tried a copy of the original OS dvd dual layer disk, the usb´s does not come up as bootable device (neither in sys prefs and when booting with alt down) but the dvd does but Ieft it on for 8 hours but it still will not boot on it just the apple and a spinning wheel. So my last option was to do a target install but then of course I'm running into the installer not running in later OS. its an old power book G4 with a ppc so no intel